# ASP.NET pass SQL statement to run in SQL Agent job

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, batch-file

Because it takes too long to export > 5 million cells to excel in my ASP.NET page, I have decided to run a SQL Agent job in the background instead and send the excel file link to the user's email inbox.

My question is how do I pass the SQL statement (which changes depending on user selection on ASP.NET page) to run to the SQL agent job? Do I need to create a stored procedure first? Then get the SQL Agent job to run the sp?

Also, how do I export the SQL result into a CSV file using the SQL Agent Job?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create SQL Server Agent Job from your ASP.NET code behind and pass custom T-SQL statement into. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms135739%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) is an example.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/drewgillson/1964274) is an example of stored procedure exporting data to CSV from T-SQL